# JIRA v4 : The Gadget Dashboard bundled plugin is not available. How to fix?

Tags: tomcat, jira, dashboard

Had to stop and restart Tomcat which includes an old install of JIRA (v4, I know its old). Upon restart I am getting

```
The Gadget Dashboard bundled plugin is not available. 
Please contact an administrator to ensure the Gadget Dashboard plugin is enabled!
```

When I go into Admin on JIRA, and scroll down to Plugins I find
Plugin currently disabled
against Gadget Dashboard plugin. I click on Enable Plugin and in the *atlassian-jira.log* I get

```
016-04-10 11:02:41,324 ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-33 WARN billy 39701x396x2 osxx3k /secure/admin/jira/ViewPlugins.jspa [atlassian.jira.plugin.JiraPluginManager] Disable Plugin Without Persisting after Plugin System Started
java.lang.RuntimeException
        at com.atlassian.jira.plugin.JiraPluginManager.disablePluginWithoutPersisting(JiraPluginManager.java:103)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.PluginEnabler.enable(PluginEnabler.java:124)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.PluginEnabler.enableRecursively(PluginEnabler.java:48)
        at com.atlassian.plugin.manager.DefaultPluginManager.enablePlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:920)
        at com.atlassian.jira.plugin.JiraPluginManager.enablePlugin(JiraPluginManager.java:56)
        at com.atlassian.jira.web.action.admin.ViewPlugins.doExecute(ViewPlugins.java:83)
        at webwork.action.ActionSupport.execute(ActionSupport.java:153)
        at com.atlassian.jira.action.JiraActionSupport.execute(JiraActionSupport.java:59)
```

Does anybody have any idea firstly what the problem is (why it is now disabled), and why the enable is not working? That exception leaves a lot to be desired in terms of helpful info.

The only other thing to add is that in Admin for that plugin I see

```
(dashboard-rest-endpoints)
Provides REST endpoints for manipulating dashboards.
Error occurred: Support for this module is not currently installed.
```

But no idea if this is a "problem" and preventing the whole plugin being enabled. If so how do i fix that first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that you can get this when trying to run JIRA v4 with Java 8, which had been upgraded separately on the server being used. Moving back to Java 7 fixed it for me.